# single layer dojo build results in "undefined./resources/blank.gif" for dijit.Menu

Tags: dojo

It seems that dijit.Menu is dependent on `dojo/resources/blank.gif` which is found when we perform a dojo build and leave it in the `release` directory. We are building a single layer - our build profile is as follows:

```
dependencies = {
 layers: [{
  name: "dojo.js",
  dependencies: ["core.bootstrap.dojo_deps"]
 }],
 prefixes: [
             ["core", "../../../core"],
             ["dijit", "../dijit"],
             ["dojox", "../dojox"]
           ]
};
```

Our problem arises when we attempt to rename dojo.js to something else. When we do that, dojo can no longer find the `dojo/resources` directory. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo_release_140_src/release/dojo/dojo/complete-build.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo_release_140_src/dijit/themes/dijit.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo_release_140_src/dijit/themes/tundra/Menu.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
     dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
     dojo.ready(function(){
         pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
             targetNodeIds: ["menu"],
             leftClickToOpen: true
         });
         pMenu.addChild(new dijit.PopupMenuItem({
             label: "Clocks"
         }));
     });
 </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <a id="menu">menu</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As shown, the browser will attempt to fetch `undefined./resources/blank.gif`; however, if we change `complete-build.js` to `dojo.js` it finds it successfully at `dojo_release_140_src/release/dojo/dojo/resources/blank.gif`. We can't keep the name as dojo.js - right now we are working around it by actually creating an `undefined.` directory at the base of our domain and sticking the image in there.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the bootstrap looks for the script tag containing 'dojo.js' in order to determine the path for loading resources.  If you must rename dojo.js, try defining [djConfig.baseUrl](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/djConfig.baseUrl) prior to the SCRIPT tag which loads your renamed Dojo.